# how to stop summation index from constantly changing

Tags: maxima

I have some expressions containing nested sums, looking like this:

[image: example]

and I want to substitute one of the summation indices(such as i369) for something else.

But the problem is, sometimes maxima seems to re-define the whole sum every time expr is called. So, every time I call second(expr) maxima tells me some new index names, instead of i369:

[image: problem]

So when I call subst, nothing happens because it sees:

[image: weird]

How to stop this from happening?

Comment: I thought about using niceindices(), but there are some very large expressions with dozens of different indices, so that wouldn't work.

Comment: I'm not seeing that behavior in either wxMaxima or command line Maxima. Some questions that might help narrow what's going on. What are the lines of code to recreate that expression? What does `grind(expr);` output? What does `?print(expr);` output? (Note the question mark preceding `print`; that means the internal Lisp PRINT function is called.) What does `wxbuild_info();` report? Do you see the same behavior in command line Maxima? Thanks for any information.

Comment: The issue can be reproduced by running:


`ratprint: false;`

`cauchysum: true;`

`sumexpand: true;`

`simpsum: false;`


`s1: sum(i^2*y*x^(i),i,0,m)+a;`

`s2: sum(i*z*x^(2*i),i,0,p)+b;`

`s3: sum(i*z^(2*i),i,0,m );`

`test:s1*s2*s3;`


`simplify_expr_for_extract(expr,eps) := block([], intosum_expand_eps(expr):=intosum(expandwrt(expr, eps)), scanmap(intosum_expand_eps,(expr)));`


`test2:simplify_expr_for_extract(test,x);`

`test3:second(second(test2));`

`test3`

Comment: `grind(test3)` gives `'sum('sum(i23^2*i24('sum(i19*x^(2*i19+i23),i19,0,p))*z^(2*i24+1),i24,0,m),i23,0,m)$` and `?print(expr);` gives 
((%SUM)
 ((%SUM)
  ((MTIMES SIMP) ((MEXPT SIMP) $I211 2) $I212
   ((%SUM SIMP)
    ((MTIMES SIMP) $I129
     ((MEXPT SIMP) $X ((MPLUS SIMP) $I211 ((MTIMES SIMP) 2 $I129))))
    $I129 0 $P)
   ((MEXPT SIMP) $Z ((MPLUS SIMP) 1 ((MTIMES SIMP) 2 $I212))))
  $I212 0 $M)
 $I211 0 $M)

Comment: I could replace all sums with a dummy function, so that maxima won't check if indices are already used. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the additional information. The changing indices are the result of `sumexpand` being true, and `test3` is a product of summations, and it's getting resimplified according to `sumexpand` every time it is evaluated. The `sumexpand` transformation assigns new indices every time it processes a summation, so that's how you're getting different indices each time you evaluate `test3`.

I think the clearest way forward is to only enable `sumexpand` when you need to process a summation, and otherwise leave it disabled. Something like `block([sumexpand: true], <whatever operations here>)` enables `sumexpand` for the duration of the block and then restores the previous value. Something like that works for global flags in general.

As an aside, bear in mind that function definitions are always global. When you write `f(x) := block(g(y) := ..., ...)`, the function `g` is not local to `f`; instead `f` and `g` are both globally defined. You can supply `lambda` expression to `scanmap` instead of a named function, or just pull the would-be local function out and define it outside of `simplify_expr_for_extract`.

Comment: Thanks. I'll switch to that.

Comment: Sorry, an additional question: what actually is the operator of sums? I tried `operatorp(sum(1*x^i, i, 0, inf), sum)`, `operatorp(sum(1*x^i, i, 0, inf), "sum")`, `operatorp(sum(1*x^i, i, 0, inf), 'sum)`, `operatorp(sum(1*x^i, i, 0, inf), "summation")`, etc and none returned true.

Comment: I'm guessing that you are intending to look for summations and then extract the arguments and process them in some way. The best way to do that in Maxima is via the pattern matching functions, `matchdeclare`, `defrule`, `defmatch`, `tellsimp`, and `tellsimpafter`. My advice is to take a look at that and maybe open another question. Probably it would help to back up a little and say something about the general goal you are aiming towards. By the way, "pattern matching" in Maxima means matching expressions, not strings (there are some functions for that too, but it's a separate topic).

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the tips. I have used pattern matching before, and the rules are more complicated than rules and patterns can work with, and I've already got a version working and tested. (I'm extracting nth order coefficient from nested power series with arbitrary bounds, so there are a lot of special cases to make sure the bounds are correct.) Anyway, `nounify(sum)` seems to do the trick for `operatorp`.